# Return from a callback function does not set text

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback

I want to know if a user is `online` or `offline`. So, I have exported a function called `isOnline` from my class.

Here is how I define my `isOnline` function:

```
export const isOnline = (callback) => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch()
           .then(result => {
                callback(null, result);
           }).catch(err => {
                callback(err);
           });
};
```

The `isOnline` function returns a `boolean`.

Now, i want to use it in a component. So, I tried to use it as follows:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Text>{
            isOnline((err, result) => {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(result);
                return result ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
            })
        }</Text>
    );
}
```

I have also logged the err and result object. The values of them are:

```
err: null
result: false
```

I expect to see Online or Offline on screen. But I don't see any text. I know that there is something wrong in my return statement. But I don't know what. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better put the Online/Offline string in the state and then update it with `componentDidMount`

For example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        isOnline((err, result) => {
            this.setState({
                text: result ? 'Online' : 'Offline'      
            });
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>{
                this.state.text
            }</Text>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function executes a callback but doesn't actually return a boolean value. You could try an approach like this:

```
export const isOnline() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch()
      .then((result) => {
        return result;
      }).catch((err) => {
        return false;
      });
}

render() {
    return (
      <Text>{isOnline() ? 'Online' : 'Offline'}</Text>
    );
}
```